# Shutting down Netty Server

Tags: netty

I have a little problem about shutting down Netty Server.
The documentation says about shutting down the server is that;

```
public class TimeServer {

static final ChannelGroup allChannels = new DefaultChannelGroup("time-server");

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ...
    ChannelFactory factory = ...;
    ServerBootstrap bootstrap = ...;
    ...
    Channel channel = bootstrap.bind(...);
    allChannels.add(channel);
    waitForShutdownCommand();
    ChannelGroupFuture future = allChannels.close();
    future.awaitUninterruptibly();
    factory.releaseExternalResources();
}
```

}

then after searching around what "waitForShutDownCommand" is, I found that it is something like a ShutdownHook method.
Well then I added a shutdownhook method to my server,

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            nettyServer.shutDown();
        }
    }, "shutDownHook"));
```

But then, I realized that when I try to quit my server with ctrl-c it is not called always. 
Because When server shutdown I want to do some operation which is related to that server. 
(Like deleting all the data from Redis which is related to that server.)

So.. I come up with an idea, but I did not implement yet, I just want to make sure that if it is a good approach or not. So, to shutdown a server I need a CLIENT (Admin Client) which sends SHUTDOWN command to that server.Actually, I did not want to create an ADMIN Client, because I don't want to care of another client application and security things etc...

So what is your solutions? Any Ideas? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

CTRL + C will not execute the shutdown hook if you are lucky enough.. Use "kill " and it will work.

Comment: But what if I need to gracefully shutdown Netty server on `SIGTERM`? I mean killing is out of the question in my specific case.